# Using powershell script to kill process but access deined

Tags: powershell

I need using powershell script to kill a process, however access denied. How can I get admin with powershell script? In addition, I do not want to input Admin account and password manually. The Get-Admin process needs to be done automatically. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: any attempt to solve it?

Comment: Yes. I tried some ways but still access denied. I do not know what the issue is. Still new to powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to elivate your script, or console prompt, to use the "run as administrator" option. A [good example script can be found here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/) on how you might do this in your script.

The meat of the script provided in the link just takes the user running the script and verify if the current session is elavated. If it is not you have to open one up as that in order to kill a process. You would also deal with UAC if you are on Windows, that if the user running it does not have local admin rights you will be prompted to enter credentials.

Snippet of the code that verifies if the execution account is admin:

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
$myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole)
```

You can find a few other options to [get elevated permissions here](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
start-process pwsh -Verb RunAs
```

or

```
start-process powershell -Verb RunAs
```

to get yourself an elevated shell. Then run the command you want